# Как при помощи AJAX получить таблицу от PHPExcel?

Tags: ajax, post, phpexcel

есть набор данных, которые хочу передать пост запросом в phpexcel и получить файл на скачивание. но приходит жуткий ответ, не переводящийся в файл

```
    <?php
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/phpexcel/export.php';
    if (isset($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $val)
        {
            if (empty($val) || $val == '')
            {  
                unset($array[$key]);            
            }
        }

        $array = 'val=' . json_encode($array);
       // $list = $array;
       // echo CHtml::textField('array', $array, array('type'=>'hidden')); 
     ?>
         <?php
       echo "<iframe id='ifr' src=http://$path/ align='left' seamless ></iframe>;";
    }
    ?>
    <div id="ajax" style="display:none" > 

    <div class="form-actions">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            var path = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
            var data = '<?php echo $array; ?>';
           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://"+path,
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                     //   document.location.href =("http://"+path);
                    $('#ajax').append(data);
                    // alert(data); 
                },
                error: function (data) { // if error occured
                    alert("Error occured.please try again");
                    alert(data);
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при том условии что PHPExcel видит запрос

```
    array(1) {
      ["val"]=>
      string(1328) "{"C2":"2619.6","D2":"9938.390","E2":"3.794","C3":"2617.4","D3":"8947.694","E3":"3.419"
    ,"C4":"2747.6","D4":"11798.216","E4":"4.294","C5":"4957.6","D5":"11422.492","E5":"2.304","C6":"4358.3"
    ,"D6":"10406.253","E6":"2.388","C7":"4167.2","D7":"10659.921","E7":"2.558","C8":"3754.7","D8":"11615
    .189","E8":"3.094","C9":"3760.7","D9":"11137.694","E9":"2.962","C10":"3931.0","D10":"12756.220","E10"
    :"3.245","C11":"4334.0","D11":"11863.712","E11":"2.737","C12":"4344.9","D12":"12074.393","E12":"2.779"
    ,"C13":"3927.9","D13":"23313.139","E13":"5.935","C14":"2440.4","D14":"7842.462","E14":"3.214","C15":"2178
    .4","D15":"7826.950","E15":"3.593","C16":"2277.6","D16":"11497.601","E16":"5.048","C17":"3880.8","D17"
    :"9659.452","E17":"2.489","C18":"3002.3","D18":"11022.939","E18":"3.671","D19":"10481.460","C20":"3700
    .2","D20":"10549.835","E20":"2.851","C21":"3784.3","D21":"10754.410","E21":"2.842","C22":"3498.9","D22"
    :"10430.293","E22":"2.981","C23":"4509.0","D23":"9002.360","E23":"1.997","C24":"3342.9","D24":"11954
    .572","E24":"3.576","C25":"3539.9","D25":"10723.942","E25":"3.029","C26":"2095.9","D26":"11159.536","E26"
    :"5.324","C27":"4358.5","D27":"11266.504","E27":"2.585","C28":"4059.7","D28":"13016.454","E28":"3.206"
    ,"C29":"5034.6","D29":"13073.626","E29":"2.597","A62":"Итого","C62":"97224.300","D62":"316195.709","E62"
    :"3.252"}"
    }
```

export.php

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

 // var_dump($_POST);
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    $array = $_POST;
//var_dump($array);
    $array = json_decode($array['val'], true);
//var_dump($array);
    $title = 'title';
    $month = date('Y-m');
//var_dump($array);

    if (!empty($array['title']))
    {
        $title = $array['title'];
        unset($array['title']);
    }
    if (!empty($array['month']))
    {
        $month = $array['month'];
    }
    unset($array['month']);
    require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

//echo $array['val'];
// Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
            ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
            ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
            ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Initialise the Excel row number
    $rowCount = 1;

    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
        )
    );

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($style);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension()->setAutoSize(true);

    $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m', strtotime($month)), date('Y', strtotime($month)));
//var_dump ($array);
    if (!empty($array['table']))
    {
          unset($array['table']);
        //var_dump($number);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A1:A2");

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Дата');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B1:B2");
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Смена');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("C1:H1");

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Средняя производительность, т/час');

        for($x = 1, $i = 3, $z = $i + 1; $x <= $number; $x++, $i+=2, $z = $i + 1) //по числу дней
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $i, $month . '-' . $x);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A" . $i . ":A" . $z);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $i, 1);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $z, 2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
//заголовок
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Дата');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Смена');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Производство промпродукта, т.');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Вода, м3');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'Уд. расход воды, м3/т');
//заголовок


        for($x = 1, $i = 2, $z = $i + 1; $x <= $number; $x++, $i+=2, $z = $i + 1) //по числу дней
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $i, $month . '-' . $x);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A" . $i . ":A" . $z);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $i, 1);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $z, 2);
        }
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        //echo "$key => $val";
        if (!empty($val))
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($key, $val);
    }

// Add some data
// Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($title);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $title . '.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
else
    return null;
```

Comment: еще похожие траблы бывают из-за кодировки файла где у вас идет генерация Excel.

Comment: utf 8 везде как и положено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вполне жизнеспособным оказался такой финт ушами

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/phpexcel/export.php';

$xlpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/phpexcel/tmp';

if (isset($array))
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if (empty($val) || $val == '')
        {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    $array = json_encode($array);

    // строка, которую будем записывать
    $text = $array;
    $name = time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.txt';
// открываем файл, если файл не существует,
//делается попытка создать его
    $fp = fopen($xlpath . '/' . $name, "w");

// записываем в файл текст
    fwrite($fp, $text);

// закрываем
    fclose($fp);

    echo "<iframe id='ifr' src=http://$path/?name=$name align='left' seamless ></iframe>";
}
```

и в файле с PHPExcel

```
$xlpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/phpexcel/tmp';

if (!empty($_GET))
{
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}

$f = fopen($xlpath . '/' . $name, "r");

// Читать строку их текстового файла и записать содержимое клиенту
$array = fgets($f);

fclose($f);
unlink($xlpath . '/' . $name);

$array = json_decode($array, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Поступите проще, сохраняйте файл средствами php, а ajax`ом возвращайте уже url на скачивание.

Comment: у меня ajaxом формируется таблица, хотел второй раз базу не дергать и передавать уже известные значения

Comment: тогда просветите, что вы хотите сделать с данными, которые отдаст вам php:\\output в javascript ?:)

Comment: как что сохранить или открыть

Comment: мне кажется, вы хотите сохранить файл средствами Java Script, только он этого не умеет, не умеет он с файлами работать. Отдавайте url на скачивание, по сути это тоже самое, разве, что чистить файлы на сервер придется, потом.

Comment: еще можно открывать ссылку, которая генерит ваш ексель, с переданными вами параметрами, тогда пользователь напрямую получить файл и не придется ничего сохранять

Comment: то есть он не сможет мне вернуть xls? и ответ не подогнать напильником? тогда проблем а в том, что данные для таблицы я получаю через аjax. на странице c excel при выполнении всех запросов посылать пост запрос на эту же страницу?

Comment: так я делал сначала.   `echo "<iframe id='ifr' src=http://$path/$array align='left' seamless ></iframe>;";` но вот ие 8 не дает записать в заголовок весь массив

Comment: "на странице c excel при выполнении всех запросов посылать пост запрос на эту же страницу?" да можно в запросе добавить параметр "saveToExcel=true" и проверять если он есть, то отдавать файл пользователю

Comment: только вот страница с таблицей это одна страница, а формирование экселя - другая. дважды одни и те же данные дергать нужно.